# User Story in a multi technology team

Tags: agile, jira

In the company, we have a team that deals with mobile; it consists of a web services part, an Android part, and an iOS part.

When we plan a sprint on Jira, we often have user stories that include tasks on all three platforms.

For example, "Do X" means "Do X on iOS," "Do X on Android," and "Do Z on WS." So we create a User Story with these three tasks.

The problem is that a User Story should be completed in one sprint, but this is not always true (maybe the WS starts earlier or Android starts later). So it is impossible for a User Story to be completed in one sprint. What do you recommend I do? I was thinking of an epic with multiple User Stories per platform, but then I wouldn't want there to be too many epics and sub-epics compared to the concept of an epic.

What do you recommend I do? What is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 5):

In a scenario like this, I would expect multiple user stories. It's not clear if "web services" means your remote system with Android and iOS clients or if it also includes a web interface. Depending on what you mean by "web services", I would expect two or three user stories.

This allows you to understand, decompose, and plan the work independently. You can also consider what order it makes sense to do the work to get feedback from key stakeholders.

If you have a single unit of work that requires you to update your iOS and Android apps, along with the web services that support those apps, you may make a large investment in a feature that isn't right. So it may be better to implement a feature on one platform first and get feedback on if the feature is viable and valuable before implementing it on other platforms. Separating the work also allows you to consider varying scopes and difficulties - some functionality may be more difficult on one platform than another.

In Jira terms, using an Epic could be a useful placeholder for these features so stakeholders can visualize the state of work and have easy access to the stories and other related work items.

Comment: Agreed, use epics. We do the same because **from a technical standpoint** the features for different platforms do not have to be rolled out at he same time (although you will want to do that as much as possible), and in our case we have cross-platform dependencies, e.g. the Android/iOS implementations wait for a user story in a Windows background service.